# Adding events from api to React Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm beginner with react. I've got a problem with passing api response to react calendar.
Calendar is in another component.

This is my initial state in main class

```
  state = {
    calendarEvents: {
      title: "All Day Event very long title",
      start: "2021-05-03T22:00:00.000Z",
      end: "2021-05-05T22:00:00.000Z",
    },
  };
```

And now I want to pass received api response to CalendarEvents state.
Response look like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "60a40304b70c7815d077632b",
        "title": "TEy",
        "start": "2021-04-29T22:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2021-05-05T22:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "60a4034db70c7815d077632c",
        "title": "TEyy",
        "start": "2021-05-04T22:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2021-05-19T22:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "60a40743b70c7815d077632d",
        "title": "TEyyy",
        "start": "2021-04-28T22:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2021-05-27T22:00:00.000Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
]
```

My function saves data to another array and replace calendarEvents in state.

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "60a40304b70c7815d077632b", title: "TEy", start: "2021-04-29T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-05T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
1: {_id: "60a4034db70c7815d077632c", title: "TEyy", start: "2021-05-04T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-19T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
2: {_id: "60a40743b70c7815d077632d", title: "TEyyy", start: "2021-04-28T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-27T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
3: {_id: "60a429fd56f28356fc0c08f1", title: "TEqy", start: "2021-05-04T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-04T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
4: {_id: "60a42a4c56f28356fc0c08f2", title: "TEqqy", start: "2021-04-27T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-04T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
5: {_id: "60a42b0556f28356fc0c08f3", title: "TEqqqy", start: "2021-04-26T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-03T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
6: {_id: "60a42d5356f28356fc0c08f6", title: "TEqqqqy", start: "2021-04-26T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-11T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
7: {_id: "60a42dfbf2769366c46def4d", title: "TEqqqqqy", start: "2021-04-27T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-11T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
8: {_id: "60a43129f2769366c46def4f", title: "undefined", start: "2021-05-04T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-11T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
9: {_id: "60a4318ff2769366c46def50", title: "v2", start: "2021-05-03T22:00:00.000Z", end: "2021-05-11T22:00:00.000Z", __v: 0}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And now I want to pass it to calendar by props
Main
 `<Calendar  eventsPassed={this.state.calendarEvents}/>`

Calendar:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "400pt" }}>
        <Calendar
          **events={this.props.eventsPassed}**
...
```

This makes a lot of errors:

index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `events` of type `object` supplied to `Calendar`, expected an array.

index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `events` of type `object` supplied to `MonthView`, expected `array`.

Uncaught TypeError: evts.filter is not a function

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method

But this works
(Calendar Class)

events = [
{

```
  title: "All Day Event very long title",
  start: "2021-05-03T22:00:00.000Z",
  end: "2021-05-05T22:00:00.000Z",
},


  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "400pt" }}>
        <Calendar
          **events={this.events}**
...
```

So even if i try to pass only state mentioned at the beggining(without api response) it makes errors too. I'm confused.
Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: try to use react devtools to preview your state is seems that your state is not of type array

Answer (score 0):

its looks like your initial state is not of type array

```
state = {
calendarEvents: {
  title: "All Day Event very long title",
  start: "2021-05-03T22:00:00.000Z",
  end: "2021-05-05T22:00:00.000Z",
},
```

};

try to wrap calandarEvents in an array this:

```
 state = {
    calendarEvents: [{
      title: "All Day Event very long title",
      start: "2021-05-03T22:00:00.000Z",
      end: "2021-05-05T22:00:00.000Z",
    },
  }];
```

for the warning you need use **componentwillunmount** to clean your component and prevent this post component code so i can help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was missing wrapping.